# Signal set functions in macOS are macros, why?

Tags: c, unix, signals, posix, bsd

I discovered that signal sets manipulation functions are defined as macros in macOS: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sigismember.3.html).
Then for instance, `sigemptyset` always results in `0` or `1`, while the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigismember.html) says that it can return `-1` on failure.

I can fallback to the `sigemptyset` function by `undef`ing it, but why is it the way it is in Mac?
Is this just one of the quarks, or `sigemptyset` can never fail on a Mac?

---

Edit: I linked the "standard" to a wrong page; it should be [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigemptyset.html). I did not change the main text as the accepted answer pointed out this mistake and wanted to make it consistent.

Comment: How can `sigemptyset()` fail?

Comment: @Shawn I don't know, but the man page says it can return `-1` and set `errno`.

Comment: Note: You should still write your code to check for the failure case. The next version of OS-X may have a way for it to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a function as both macro and as a true function is permissible and even encouraged practice (as, e.g., a macro that expands to efficient, inline assembly).  Per POSIX:

> 2. Any function declared in a header may also be implemented as a macro defined in the header, so a function should not be declared explicitly if its header is included. [...]

(*[POSIX.1-2017 Vol. 2 §2.1.1 Use and Implementation of Functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html)*)

With respect to the return values of `sigemptyset`, the [standard defines no specific errors](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigemptyset.html) for that function, meaning it is not required to detect any errors.  The `sigismember` function (to which you link under the name `sigemptyset`) [has a specified error](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigismember.html), but it is an optional "may fail" rather than a mandatory "shall fail" error detection.  OS X, as you see in its documentation, detects no errors at all.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the POSIX manual! To make things clear, if the standard defines no specific errors, should I still check if the `errno` has changed, or am I being too pedantic here?

Comment: @JayLee yeah you should generally check — informed by your local implementation (e.g., OS X man pages, etc.) — if warranted.  I'd personally often skip it for these functions, because I know I'm operating on defined `sigset_t`objects with known SIGFOO values.  Sorry, I know that "use your discretion" isn't always a clear  guideline, but I do think it's appropriate here.